# Https webservice php

Tags: php, web-services, soap

Keep getting could not connect to host this is the server code that I have

```
  <?php 
  ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled',0);
  ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl',0);

  $soap_server = new SoapServer('Notification.wsdl');
  $soap_server->addFunction('Notify');

  function Notify($message)
  {
      return array('message' => $message);
  }

  $soap_server->handle();


  ?>
```

And this is my client code which is what is throwing the error. The endpoint is https. the wsdl file is local.

```
    <?php


     $context = stream_context_create(array(

      'https' => array(
      'cafile' => 'APX_WS_API1.cer',
      'verify_peer' => true
      )
      ));

     $soap_client = new SoapClient('http://localhost:8888/Receiver/Notification.wsdl', 
      array('stream_context' => $context,'local_cer' => 'APX_WS_API1.cer'));

     try{
     $result = $soap_client->__soapCall('Notify',array('message' => 'Hello World'));
     echo $result;
      }catch(SoapFault $e){
      echo "Error: " . $e->faultstring;
      }


         ?>
```

Could someone please tell me what am i doing wrong. Thanks in advance

Comment: `new SoapClient('http://loc..` => `new SoapClient('https://loc..`. Giving the context just https options does not mean anything when that's not its transport.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response now i'm getting the Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://localhost:8888/Receiver/Notification.wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://localhost:8888/Receiver/Notification.wsdl" in C:\wamp\www\Receiver\soap_client.php:13 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp\www\Receiver\soap_client.php(13): SoapClient->SoapClient('https://localho...', Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\wamp\www\Receiver\soap_client.php on line 13

Answer (score 1):

Is your certificate valid?
Try this option:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
            'ssl' => array(
                'verify_peer' => false,
                'allow_self_signed' => true
            )
        ));
```

If it works that means your cert is invalid.

Comment: Can your local machine connect to the remote server? Try pinging the remote server.

Comment: Does anyone have any advice on what I'm doing wrong. I've been stuck on this thing for several days now.

Comment: Have you tried accessing: http://localhost:8888/Receiver/Notification.wsdl via web browser. Does it return a valid wsdl definition?